# How to save FTP session logs in file in Linux

Tags: linux, bash, ftp

I am using a bash script in Linux to transfer files to a server. My script is running from cron and I have directed output to a file but I cannot know from logs if the file has been transferred to B server or not.

This is the cron:

```
1>>/home/owais/script_test/logs/res_sim_script.logs 2>>/home/owais/script_test/logs/res_sim.logs
```

And the FTP is as below:

```
cd ${dir}

ftp -n $HOST <<END_SCRIPT

quote USER $USER

quote PASS $PASSWD


lcd $dir

cd $destDir

bin

prompt

put FILENAME

bye
```

The only thing that I get in the logs is:

```
Local directory now Directory_Name

Interactive mode off.
```

Comment: Your script misses the end of `END_SCRIPT`. Did you test the script manually (outside of cron)?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using FTP, there is `rsync`. Rsync is a fast and extraordinarily versatile file copying tool. It can copy locally, to or from another host over any remote shell, or to, or from a remote `rsync` daemon.

More information at the following webpage, https://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync

Answer (score 0):

I have used ftp -inv Host << EOF >> LogFilePath and it worked. Thank you all for the support